# how to run python files in windows command prompt?

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line, cmd, command

I want to run a python file in my command prompt but it does nothing.
These are the screen shots of my program i am testing with and the output the command prompt gives me.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Here is google search link - https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20install%20and%20configure%20python%20on%20windows

Comment: Please don't post text as images...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First set path of `python`  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7)

and run `python` file

`python filename.py`

command line argument with python

`python filename.py command-line argument`

Answer (score 4):

You have to `install` [Python](https://www.python.org) and add it to [PATH](https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html) on `Windows`. After that you can try:

```
python `C:/pathToFolder/prog.py`
```

or go to the files directory and execute:

```
python prog.py
```

Answer (score 2):

First go to the directory where your python script is present by using-

```
cd path/to/directory
```

then simply do:

```
python file_name.py
```