# How to run a simple python script in the command line/on a interpreter?

Tags: python

I am feeling quite stuck and discouraged and I am sure I am doing something wrong that must be very simple. I have saved a file in my documents called input_test.py but when I try to run it in the cmd line i get the following error:

[image]

Can anyone tell me why? What am I missing?

Comment: exit python and then type `python input_test.py`

Comment: first result when i search for "run a python script" https://realpython.com/run-python-scripts/

Comment: You are within the python shell. Just quit (using `quit()`) and type `python input_test.py` in the command prompt directly.

Comment: It now says no such file or directory. How do I ensure I am in the right directory?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to run python files in windows command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39462632/how-to-run-python-files-in-windows-command-prompt)