# I am having trouble opening .py files

Tags: python, pip

I am having trouble opening .py files. when I run the code, it opens gpython.exe and then also it does'nt execute it. I have reinstalled python(version 3.6). but then also it opens gpython.exe
[It opens gython.exe as seen in the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wk5mv.png)[Same with VS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjtYJ.png)

also when I have to install any python module through pip it opens gpython.exe
please help me solve this error
using
Windows - 10 32 bit,
python version - 3.6

Comment: I'm not sure what `gpython.exe` is, although I did find a project with that name that seems to integrate python and go. Perhaps you've installed some software that has a gpython.exe and it took over the file association for .py. On the command line you could run `ftype` and `assoc` to see what your associations are.

Comment: I'm guessing you installed `gpython` and associated it with the `.py` extensions. Is there a reason you installed it? The simplest solution would be to uninstall it, and possibly uninstall/reinstall CPython (the reference interpreter) to explicitly associated it (or more precisely, the `py.exe` launcher) with the `.py` file type.

Comment: This is the way to run python file : (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39462632/how-to-run-python-files-in-windows-command-prompt)
But try to uninstall and reinstall : (https://www.python.org/downloads/)
And the check python installed or not : type python and press Enter in cmd

Answer (score 0):

Use `python3 [file name]` for python 3.

Comment: But it should be okay to run the python file directly on Windows without prefixing with "python3".